# Can not configure a domain on microsoft azure

Tags: windows, azure, dns

I am trying to point a name.com domain to our website on microsoft azure. I tried multiple things but the system is not accepting it on Azure...

I have added 4 CNAME records and one A Record as follows:

1. awverify.mydomain.net to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net (CNAME)
2. awverify.www.mydomain.net to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net (CNAME)
3. mydomain.net to mydomain.azurewebsites.net (CNAME)
4. www.mydomain.net to mydomain.azurewebsites.net (CNAME)
5. mydomain.net to IP shown on azure (A Record)

It's a .NET top level domain purchased on name.com ... Also, around 24 hours have passed since I updated these records on name.com so it should not probably be a dns propagation issue. Please suggest it I am doing anything wrong...

When I try to add mydomain.net on windows azure... this is the error that I am consistently getting...

A CNAME record pointing from  mydomain.net to mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.mydomain.net to awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net was not found either.

Also a suggestion if anybody from microsoft azure checks this question... Why is it not possible to simply add a name server for windows azure websites like most of the other hosting providers? It's a lot more simpler and straight forward to do it this way. Isn't it?

Comment: Why not contact Azure support directly?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I finally ended up doing. Their support is paid so was trying to avoid it at the first place.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was that in the Azure Portal `->` Web Apps `->` Configure `->` Domain Names `->` Manage Domains section, I needed to enter **www.mydomain.com** not simply **mydomain.com**.

I had setup a single CNAME record pointing from the host www to MyWebAppNameXYZ.azurewebsites.net as instructed in the Azure docs. They really need to be a bit clearer around this in the various docs and popup messages.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this problem.

It so turns out that you need to add default name.com name servers as well when you add dns records.

Simply added ns1.name.com, ns2.name.com, ns3.name.com and ns4.name.com in the name servers and with that added, the same set of dns records started working just fine.